# How do I efficiently update the color of a pixel in a numpy image array if it is closer to one color in a palette than any other color?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array for an image, `img`:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.random.rand(100,100,3) * 255
```

And a list of colors, `palette`

```
white = np.array([255,255,255])
red = np.array([255,0,0])
blue = np.array([0,0,255])
palette = np.array([white, red, blue])
```

How do I create a new image array, `new_img`, where every pixel that is closer, through euclidean distance, to white than any of the other colors in the palette is changed to white (`[255,255,255]`) and every other pixel color is left as is. (It would be nice to be able to change distance functions, but not a hard requirement.)

I am able to do this the naive way with `for` loops iterating over each pixel, but it's of course a lot slower than it probably needs to be.

Comment: It depends on how do you define distance, for example `RED=[255,0,0]` is at the same distance from `BLACK[0,0,0]` than `BLUE=[0,0,255]`, and the same than this GREY=`[85,85,85]` or `[42,84,129]`

Comment: Human perception is not linearly mathematical. Look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

Comment: Palettizing an image is a common problem, and there is no good shortcut solution.  You need to do it pixel by pixel.

Comment: Thank you all for the insights! Yes, I definitely want to experiment with other measures of color difference. For my small problem though, this is doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First find the distance with every vector and then find the index of the minimum distance.

```
import numpy as np

img = np.random.rand(100,100,3) * 255
white = np.array([255,255,255])
red = np.array([255,0,0])
blue = np.array([0,0,255])
palette = np.array([white, red, blue])

palette_type = np.linalg.norm(img[...,None,:]-palette[:,:], axis=-1).argmin(axis=-1) ## 0 stands for white, 1 for red and 2 for blue.

new_img  = palette[palette_type]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so much faster than my approach. I also added a few lines to make the white pixels transparent and keep all other pixels their original color.  I'll share that in a code block in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Murali for [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73159881/19643790) that immensely helped. I took that:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.random.rand(100,100,3) * 255
white = np.array([255,255,255])
red = np.array([255,0,0])
blue = np.array([0,0,255])
palette = np.array([white, red, blue])

palette_type = np.linalg.norm(img[...,None,:]-palette[:,:], axis=-1).argmin(axis=-1) ## 0 stands for white, 1 for red and 2 for blue.

new_img  = palette[palette_type]
```

And added a few lines to take it a little further by making the white pixels transparent and kept all other pixels as their original color:

```
mask = np.all(new_img == white, axis=-1)
img_copy = img.copy()
img_copy[mask] = white
h,w, _ = img_copy.shape
transparent_img = np.dstack((img_copy, np.zeros((h,w),dtype=np.uint8)+255))
masked_white = (transparent_img[:, :, 0:3] == white).all(2)
transparent_img[masked_white] = [0,0,0,0]
```